# Guestbook Dead or Alive?

Tags: website-features

today i remembered one of my sites from 1999. It was on of my first.
In those days it was the state of the art to use a guestbook?
I never used one since then again.

Are there any webmaster/designer/devs who still use this relic from the old days?

Comment: Oh.. wait a moment... Did I just write to your guestbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think that** *guestbooks* are evolved to site forums and while client side scripting and browser DOM manipulation is lot easier today there is, for example, ability to add comments straight below products or articles on sites.

Almost every newspaper websites uses some kind of *guestbook* in form of ability to add comments to article.

Maybe we should ask *What actually is guestbook and how it is best defined?*

#### Technology changes and so changes guestbooks...

How would you like to write your message to *Guestbook*: [www.helsinkiguestbook.fi](http://www.helsinkiguestbook.fi/web/)
Is this guestbook just for comments: [www.parizs.ewebsite.com](http://www.parizs.ewebsite.com/articles/guestbook.html)
Another "guestbook": [plus.google.com](https://plus.google.com/)

### Final answer

Yes! Guestbooks definitely are alive and well. Also there is many more traditional guestbooks found at many websites; personal, community and industrial. Little [googling](http://www.lmgtfy.com?q=Guestbook) around and you can found many traditional (*even if same site has new comment system and uses facebook api's*) and still active guestbooks for example for collecting words that does not fit to other categories and/or pages.

Answer (score 2):

They exist these days in the form of comments, facebook, and share buttons. Aside from the odd relic I haven't seen one in forever and can't really see the point in having one.